# Is the following inequality correct? How to prove it?

Tags: probability, distributions

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two arbitrary random variables, and we have the following inequality that conditional on $Y=y$,
$$\textbf{Pr}(X \ge a_0 | Y=y)\le f(y),$$ 
where $\textbf{Pr}(\cdot)$ denotes the probability of the event, $a_0$ is a constant, and $f(y)$ is an increasing function with respect to $y$. I want to know whether the following inequality is correct,
$$\textbf{Pr}(X \ge a_0 , Y\le b_0)\le f(b_0),$$
where $b_0$ is a constant.

If it is wrong, is there any counter example? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expand using product rule:

$$P(X \ge a_0 \cap Y \le b_0) = P(X \ge a_0 | Y \le b_0) P(Y \le b_0)$$

Assuming $P(Y \le b_0)$ is nonzero, you can use the first inequality to obtain:

$$P(X \ge a_0 | Y \le b_0) P(Y \le b_0) \le f(y\le b_0) P(Y \le b_0)$$

Because $f(y)$ is increasing in $y$, $f(y \le b_0) \le f(b_0)$ so the inequality of interest holds.

By the way, in the context of probability $f$ is normally used for PDFs so you may want to use a different letter to avoid confusion.

EDIT: Granted, $f(y \le b_0)$ is an abuse of notation. It should be read as $f(y), y \le b_0$ and not as the function taking a set for its argument.

Comment: This looks like a fine answer, regardless of whether $P(y\le b_0)$ is nonzero.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The first inequality in the question should be $\textbf{Pr}(X \ge a_0 | Y=y)\le f(y)$, which is more accurate. How can we obtain $\textbf{Pr}(X \ge a_0 | Y \le b_0) \le f(Y \le b_0)$? What does $f(Y \le b_0)$ mean?

Comment: I always saw books made that exception when giving the formula for conditional probability. I never was too sure if it was just to keep zero out of the denominator or if allowing that possibility could have more dire implications that were merely glossed over. Given your comment, I'm assuming it was the former all along!

Comment: @ZHANGWei To be more precise, we should write $P(X \ge a_0 | Y = y) \le f(y), y \le b_0$. This way we avoid making it look like the value of $f$ is random.

Comment: @Manuel Fazio I am little confused about the correctness of $P(X \ge a_0 | Y \le b_0) \le f(y\le b_0)$. How can we arrive at this from the first inequality in the question?

Answer (score 3):

First, we have
$$\eqalign{
\textbf{Pr}(X \ge a_0|Y = y) &=\int_{a_0}^{+\infty}p_{X}(x|Y= y)dx \\
&=\int_{a_0}^{+\infty}\frac{p_{X,Y}(x,y)}{p_Y(y)}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{p_Y(y)}\int_{a_0}^{+\infty}{p_{X,Y}(x,y)}dx,
}$$
where $p_{X,Y}(x, y)$ is the joint PDF of $(X,Y)$, $p_{X}(x| Y=y)$ is the  PDF of $X$ conditional on $Y=y$, and $p_Y(y)$ is the PDF of $Y$. 
Because when $y \le b_0$, $f(y)\le f(b_0)$, that is 
$$\int_{a_0}^{+\infty}{p_{X,Y}(x,y)}dx \le f(b_0)p_Y(y)  $$
Finally, substitute it into the following,
$$\eqalign{
\textbf{Pr}(X \ge a_0, Y \le b_0) &= \int_{a_0}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{b_0}p_{X,Y}(x, y)dy dx \\
&\le \int_{-\infty}^{b_0} f(b_0)p_Y(y) dy \\
& \le f(b_0),
}$$ 
which proves the required inequality.

Comment: The notation is bad. Pr(Y=y) should be a probability density for Y.

Comment: @Michael Chernick Thanks for your comment, and I have modified the answer.

Comment: That is better.